# How to unsubscribe from FCM notifications after logout from app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase cloud messaging in my app for push notifications. Everything working fine. But notifications are getting even user logged out from app.

I heard that, I need to delete the FCM token when user logged out from app.

So I did like this in logout method:

```
-(void)logout{
        [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] deleteIDWithHandler:^(NSError *error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];
}
```

But this is not working and next time when user logged in         `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID]token]` is coming as `null`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* delete the token, but it's better to simply cancel the subscription. How to do that, depends on how you subscribed to the updates in the first place.

If you [subscribed to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic), you'll want [unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#-unsubscribefromtopic) when the user signs out.

Comment: I am subscribing to topics like this        [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/global"];        So when user signs out I have to do like this     [[FIRMessaging messaging] unsubscribeFromTopic:@"/topics/global"]; right?

Comment: Yup, that would be the way to unsubscribe from the same topic.

Comment: but I can see this is for the FCM messaging. Is this same for FCM notifications also?

Comment: Yes, Firebase Notifications is essentially just a wrapper around Firebase Cloud Messaging. But since you mentioned FCM in your original post, I liked only to the docs for FCM. I suggest that you just give it a spin and report back if you're still having problems?

Comment: @himanth It's not advisable for you to delete the token every time the user logs out. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40589815/4625829).