# Delete specific token GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an `InstanceID`. I get two **differentt** tokens for a **different app server**:

```
token1 = instanceID.getToken()
token2 = instandeID.getToken()
```

Can I delete a specific token, for example `token1`?

Answer (score 0):

You could with [deleteInstanceId](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589815/4625829). Although this would resort in the InstanceId service to generate a new one.

It's intended behavior for each server to generate it's own Registration token for each app instance.

Comment: Ok, is `SenderID`. I mean: Can I send SenderID from AppServer to an app?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you send the SenderId to your client app?

Comment: How multiple (independent!) app servers can send a notification to my app?